# How to fix missing image resources in Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I added use_frameworks! to my Podfile, and now some images resources are missing from Pods–when I run the project the images that are contained in those Pods no longer appear. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the Pods as a framework, the image files will be put in the framework, rather than the main bundle. The code in the Pods will need to specify the bundle for the framework when creating `UIImage` objects.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"
                            inBundle:bundle
       compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```